# Where can I find ReSharper plugin reference or documentation?

Tags: plugins, sdk, resharper

I would like to develop an open-source resharper 6 plug-in but I fail to locate the references to the API, resharper is a huge product to say the least and finding how to do things is next to impossible without some kind of direction.

Where can I find API docs?

Comment: Must be somewhere on the JetBrains site.  There isn't another source.

Comment: There is a very basic, amateur looking wiki there, there must be something better.

Comment: ReSharper is a JetBrains product; I'm not aware of any other source.  Perhaps you should dig deeper on their site or post the question on their forum.  They will know best.

Answer (score 2):

There is no public reference documentation that covers all of the Resharper classes and members.

If you are just starting out then I recommend you download the SDK and take a look at the included samples. There are several of them in the [SDK](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/index.html) and they should help you get started developing some Resharper plugin features.

You can use Intellisense and the Object Browser in VS to *discover* the classes and methods to use and the [plugin development guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6+Plugin+Development) should get you the rest of the way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the "amateur" wiki you referred to:

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6+Plugin+Development

Did you judge the book by its cover, or did you try the information it contains and find it wanting?

It looks to me like the details you seek are available by clicking on the topic in the blue squares.

Comment: It is the wiki, it has basic information but resharper had thousands of classes and methods, it's not open-source so there is no way to know how to do things

Comment: @DavidMZ This is all there is, and it's expanding. It will help if you ask specifically what kind of information you're looking for that the documentation is lacking. You can ask questions here on SO, or in [ReSharper Open API forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper/resharper_open_api), or by commenting docs directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the current, and public, ReSharper DevGuide for the [ReSharper Platform](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/Intro/ReSharperPlatform.html). "This is the primary source of documentation for developing extensions for the ReSharper Platform that ships as part of ReSharper.